# Cors changes Apache Tomcat/8.0.23 to Apache Tomcat/8.0.47

Tags: tomcat8

I apologise in advance as im not a programmer/developer. We have a website that perform a request to another site (ON the same domain) to etrieve dates from a Team Calendars

We recently had an application that was upgraded. As a result of the upgrade Tomcat was also upgraded form 8.0.23 to 8.0.47, since the upgrade we get the following error.

Failed to load https://: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://' is therefore not allowed access.

From what i can see in conf/web.xml and  WEB-INF/web.xml on both the upgraded and older version there is no mention or any config for CORS filters.

did something change between these Tomcat Versions that could affect this

Thanks